# append text and picture to an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'd like ask a question about image processing in Java.

What I'm looking to achieve is to put a text below an existing image. Not over the existing image, but to append to image bottom. I have googled for that, but all the answers were the suggestions how to do the latter - how to put text on image.

Below is the example picture what result I wish to have. The original picture is the Leena image and the result by image processing is together with below the red dotted lines.

[image: desired result]

What could be fastest way to achieve this - write some text below image and also append another smaller picture?

What I thought about doing is that I append to my exisitng BufferedImage bottom 30 pixels height of white background and then write to that place a text and add a logo. Could this be most efficient approach? Are there some libs that would do that work for me or is there better approach than i mentioned?

EDIT: For better clarity I want the result as a single picture

Comment: div for the image. div for the text

Comment: @gmustudent Sorry, I meant the result to be a single picture and do it in Java

Comment: where are you displaying the image when it's ready? browser?

Comment: When adding captions to my pictures, I made a class that would display an image, and display some text below it. Then I realized that I didn't like this because of poor looking fonts and did the same thing in html using google api fonts. I then made a java class to screenshot that certain area. You could try something like this, not sure how useful it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take some time to have a read through

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

This is a really basic example.  I've not bothered with adding the code to actually render a logo, you can read through the suggested reading list and should be able to figure out how that would be achieved ;)

[image]

```
public class AppendImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AppendImage();
    }

    public AppendImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage sourceImage;
        private BufferedImage labeledImage;

        public ImagePane() {

            try {
                sourceImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/source.jpg"));
                labeledImage = addLabel("Hello", sourceImage);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int width = sourceImage.getWidth() + labeledImage.getWidth();
            int height = labeledImage.getHeight();

            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        protected BufferedImage addLabel(String label, BufferedImage sourceImage) {

            Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(font);
            int width = sourceImage.getWidth() + 2;
            int height = sourceImage.getHeight() + 4 + fm.getHeight() + 4;

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
            g2d.drawImage(sourceImage, 1, 1, this);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 10f, new float[]{10f}, 0f));
            g2d.drawLine(0, sourceImage.getHeight() + 2, image.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight() + 2);

            int y = sourceImage.getHeight() + (((image.getHeight() - sourceImage.getHeight()) - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + 2;
            g2d.drawString(label, 2, y + fm.getAscent());

            String logo = "Logo here";
            int x = image.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(logo) - 12;
            g2d.drawString(logo, x, y + fm.getAscent());

            g2d.dispose();

            return image;

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 0;
            g.drawImage(sourceImage, x, 0, this);
            x += sourceImage.getWidth();
            g.drawImage(labeledImage, x, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```